# how can I enable CRCs in EZstream or FFMPEG?

Tags: stream, ffmpeg, mp3, crc, icecast

I want to detect a corrupt MP3 stream, the encoder is using CRC.

How can I enable CRC?. I want to be able to read through the headers of each frame to find the CRC, and then run it on the audio data. In the event I get an error (or several frames with errors), I can then somehow trigger a warning.

I am new to this so I can't tell what to do or how to accomplish this.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but have you found a way to achieve this?